# Is there a minimal structure in a finite signature with this property?

Tags: model-theory

Does there exist an infinite minimal structure $M$ in a finite signature, such that every finite and every cofinite subset of $M$ is definable without parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes: $(\mathbb{N},S,0)$, where $S$ is the successor function. The point is that every element of $\mathbb{N}$ is named by a term, so there is no difference between definability with and without parameters.

It's an exercise for you to prove that this structure is minimal, if you don't know it already. First, prove that its complete theory eliminates quantifiers.